# get transform component via string to track player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to grab the transform component via t.find and then via the transform component, grab the game object component, and then t.LookAt can work, and look at the player.

this is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class gunner : MonoBehaviour
{
    //legacy statements: isShot
    //these statements initialize all the main variables used in the project. most of these are for the "ai".
    #region variables
    [Header("gun stats")]
    [Space(10)]
    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;
    [Space(10)]
    [Header("Camera")]
    [Space(10)]
    public Camera cam;
    [Space(10)]
    [Header("AI Variables")]
    [Space(10)]
    public float shootlength;
    public bool aiactive;
    public float Speed;
    public target self;
    public Transform t;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public string playername = "Player";
    public GameObject PlayerObject;
    public Transform PlayerTrans;
    [Header("Decor")]
    public ParticleSystem ps;
    AudioSource audioData;
    #endregion
    #region gunmanager
    private void Start()
    {
        GameObject PlayerObject = GameObject.Find(playername);
        Transform PlayerTrans = PlayerObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if(aiactive && PlayerTrans != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("player trans found!");
        }

        if(aiactive && PlayerObject != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("player gameObject found!");
        }
        if(aiactive && PlayerTrans != null && PlayerObject != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("test passed!");
        }
        audioData = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && !aiactive)
        {
            audioData.Play(0);
            Shoot();
        }
        if(aiactive)
        {
            
            StartCoroutine(aiman());
        }
    }
    public void Shoot()
    {
        ps.Play();
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit:" + hit.transform.name);
            target targ = hit.transform.GetComponent<target>();
            
            if (targ != null)
            {   
                if(!aiactive)
                {
                    self.hp += 50;
                }
                targ.TakeDamage(damage);
                
            }
        }
    }
    public void aiActivity()
    {
        if(self.hp >= 0)
        {
            t.LookAt(PlayerTrans);
            rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
            RaycastHit hitplayer;
            if(Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out hitplayer, shootlength))
            {
                if(hitplayer.transform == PlayerObject)
                {
                    Shoot();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rb.useGravity = true;
            aiactive = false;   
        }
        
    }
    IEnumerator aiman() 
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        aiActivity();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

so no compiler errors, but it cannot find the player and float towards it, and therefore, I cannot get this to work.

Comment: You mention a string and getting the player, but I do not see any code reflecting this? Are you asking how you get a Transform by the string literal of its name? If so, use [`Transform.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html). Just pass in the objects name as the string parameter.

Comment: If you are saying you want to use the `Shoot` raycast to detect the player object, then exclude all other layers in your cast. In the fourth parameter of a [`Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) you can pass in a [`LayerMask`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html). Pass in a mask that just includes the layer the player is on. If this is not answering your question can you clarify what you mean in your question? As `get the name of an object, then a game object variable finds the player from the string containing the method` is not too clear.

Comment: @TEEBQNE changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few issues with the updated snippet, not sure if they will fix all of the errors you are getting.

You are re-using a variable name `t`. I would also refrain from naming any global variables very short random letters as it can get confusing. What is this a `Transform` of? If it is the transform of a player, possibly name it `PlayerTransfom`.

As I mentioned you are re-using a variable name which is not allowed especially with different types as well as re-initilization. It is fine to re-assign a variable such that it is updated, manipulating, changing, etc. the value, but re-declaring the value is not allowed in c# and I do not believe allowed in any other language (at least that I know of).

To be specific, the line `target t = hit.transform.GetComponent<target>();` is delcaring `t` as the script component type `target`, but you have already declared a `Transform` named `t` above it as `public Transform t;`.

Another issue is you are attempting to assign a variable using a non-static method in a global setting. The line specifically is `public Transform player = Transform.Find(playername);`. You are not able to set the transform like this outside of a method as the `Find` method is not static. Change it to be.

```
public Transform player;

private void Start()
{
     player = Transform.Find(playername);
}
```

The second error is because of the same reason, but due to this line `public GameObject PlayerObject = player.GetComponent<GameObject>();`. Again, `GetComponent` is a nonstatic method so can not be called in a global setting. The other issue is `GameObject` is not a component, it is a type. `GameObjects` have components so you can not get the component of itself as it does not exist. You are already using `Transform.Find` which finds a transform, I would recommend just finding the `GameObject`, storing that reference then get the `Transform` from the gameObject. You do not really need to store the transform as its own reference if you have the `GameObject` reference though.

```
public Transform player;
public GameObject PlayerObject;

private void Start()
{
     PlayerObject = GameObject.Find(playername);
     player = PlayerObject.transform;
}
```

The final error being outputted is specifying that you are using [`LookAt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) incorrectly. You need to pass in a type of `Transform`, but you are passing in a type of `GameObject`. Change it to...

```
t.LookAt(player);
```

Most of these issues are rather trivial and straightforward. I would follow along with a tutorial or read through the docs to get a better understanding of C#/Unity/Programming. Being a beginner is fine, but StackOverflow should not just be used as debugging help when the errors are right there. I do not know if the 4 recommendations I mentioned will fully fix your program as I did not run it. There could be more issues than what I had mentioned, but following the errors should tell you what is wrong and why it is wrong. It is printing the line number, file, and reason for why it is breaking.

Comment: yeah, sorry, im just nine so Im kinda sucky

Comment: @AeneasTheBadDeveloper No worries. Everyone's gotta start somewhere. It might help to look into some [c# tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhQdlIFylQ8&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org) or to follow along with game tutorials like the ones you can find on [Brackey's](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYbK_tjZ2OrIZFBvU6CCMiA) channel. Were you able to solve your current issues with the write-up I made? Or are you still having trouble?

Comment: so there are no compiler errors, however it can't track the player

Comment: like they do absolutely nothing

Comment: @AeneasTheBadDeveloper Well that's a step in the right direction at least. Can you delete and update the code in your post? I can try to see what the issue is.

Comment: kk did so check it now

Comment: @AeneasTheBadDeveloper I see a few reasons the code might not work. Would you mind explaining your goal for your AI to do? I can try to clean up the code and add comments to help you understand. Do you want the AI to move in a random direction every so often unless the player gets close, then you want them to shoot the player?

Comment: I just fixed it

Comment: just fixed it, and I was making two variables with the same name, it works now

Comment: @AeneasTheBadDeveloper Awesome! Glad you got it working. If you feel my post helped answer your question you can accept it by hitting the check symbol to the left of the post. It let's others know the question is answered and closed. Unless you have other issues related to the question I can help with?

Comment: god damn it my project got corrupted

Comment: What do you mean by corrupted?

Comment: uhhh yeah so it was just one script funkin the entire thing up